# Lightbox2 on specific pages only

Tags: 7, media, javascript

there's option setting on Lightbox2 General settings tab:
[image]

And there's my Basic Page's content type settings for Image field:
[image]

So no matter what, but it applies the Lightbox2 to all Basic Page nodes that has content in the image field. What I want is that it would apply those settings from the Format Settings only to the Image field at `node/72`. What's wrong and what is the use of Page specific settings?

Comment: Try prettyPhoto and some JQuery code? 72 gets printed somewhere as a class on the body tag of node/72 page.

Comment: This isn't really a solution to your problem, but any reason why you choose lightbox2 over [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/node/1971564)? It's still being actively developed and I've just used it to do pretty much that exact thing. (Not sure what diff in plugin size is. Colorbox is 4.7kb compressed)

Comment: Please use Answer button so I could select correct answer.